# How to apply CSS to AutoComplete' List from rsuite component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, autocomplete, dropdown, rsuite

I'm tryin to apply style to the list of this component from Rsuite:

https://rsuitejs.com/components/auto-complete#%3CAutoComplete%3E

I wanna set a max-height, and overflow.

At the moment I tried to set style={{maxHeight: 150px}} but it applies to the InputContainer not the List.

Answer (score 1):

You can target the popup list via css using the `div.rs-picker-menu` selector:

```
div.rs-picker-menu {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-voice-z81pw?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: thnks, but it didnt work.

im using styled-components to css components 

I tryied the following code.. 

const Autocomplete = styled(AutoComplete)`
    .rs-picker-menu {
        background-color: red;
        color: red;
    }
`

just to let u know, i set color to see if it works propertly.

Comment: You didn't mention you were using styled components. If you look at my sandbox you see it does work using regular css. You can just add the css I posted in a css file and include that.

Comment: @Nehlk I wouldn't recommend trying to style this using the styled components, because `rs-picker-menu` is rendered outside the entry point `root` div scope (This is probably done using [React portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)). Instead it's easier to target it using regular css as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Thnk y so much. It worked without styled-components !!

Comment: @Nehlk Glad to help. If this solved the problem be sure to upvote and accept the answer to show the answer resolved your issue.